# Primes $P_{2n-1}$ that are $2$ mod $3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Are infinitely many primes $P_{2n-1}$ expressible as $3k-1$?

The primes $P_{2n-1}$ are every other prime beginning with $2$: [$2,5,11,17,23,31,\cdots$](https://oeis.org/A031368). The first few are of the form $3k-1$, but $31$ is not.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvotes?

Comment: @Lucia: I guess you like my edit.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Ok, that makes sense!  And yes, I like your edit!

Answer (score 12):

A paper by Kisilevsky and Rubinstein (available here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4945) shows that any set of primes determined by ``Chebotarev conditions'' can't be too regularly distributed within the primes.  The set of primes in any union of residue classes (e.g. $2 \pmod{3})$ is a Chebotarev set of primes, so can't be too regularly distributed within the primes as a whole.  Meanwhile, the set of primes of odd index are very regularly distributed within the primes, so they can't be a Chebotarev set.

See Corollary 1 in the linked paper.

Answer (score 10):

It was known since Littlewood, "Distribution des Nombres Premiers", C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 158 (1914), 1869-1872, that there are infinitely many $x$ for which $\pi(x,3,1)>\pi(x,3,2)$ as well as infinitely many $x$ for which $\pi(x,3,2)>\pi(x,3,1)$. This implies that there can't be only finitely many primes $p_{2n-1}$ that are $2\pmod{3}$. For a more detailed account of more powerful and accurate results check out the Rubinstein, Sarnak paper on the Chebyshev bias.